# I fill the login form and click on submit button and page is reloaded and email id is blank how to get email id text filled?

Tags: php

I fill the login form and click on submit button and page is reloaded and email id is blank how to get email id text filled?
This is the php code.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
{   
if($_POST["txtEmail"]=="")
{
    $errormsg = "Please enter Email.";

}
else if($_POST["txtPassword"]=="")
{
    $errormsg = "Please enter Password.";
}

else
{

    $Email =  $_POST["txtEmail"];

    $Password =  md5($_POST["txtPassword"]);

    $info = mysql_query("select * from tbluser where Email ='$Email' and Password='$Password'");

    $count_info=mysql_num_rows($info);

    if($count_info>0)
    {
            while($a = mysql_fetch_array($info))
            {
                $b = strcmp($a["Email"],$Email);

                if($b==0 && $a["Password"]=="$Password" && $a["IsVisible"]==1)
                {   
                    $_SESSION["UserId"] = $a["user_id"];
                    $_SESSION["UserName"] = $a["user_name"];
                    header("Location:index.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    $errormsg="Register Your Account First.";
                }
            }
    }
    else
    {
        $errormsg="Invalid email or password.";
    }

}

}
?>
```

end of php code.

Starting of form tag.

```
<form name="login" method="post">
          <table id="form">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        if($errormsg!="")
                        {
                    ?>
                            <span id="errorPassword" style="padding-left:10px; color:#C00;"> <?php echo $errormsg; ?> </span>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="width:200px;">Email: <span style="color:#F00">*</span></td>
                <td style="width:300px;"><input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email" /></td>
                <td style="width:200px;"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password: <span style="color:#F00">*</span></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" /></td>
                <td><span id="errorEmail" style="padding-left:10px; color:#C00;"></span></td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td align="left" ><input type="submit" id="form_button" name="btnSubmit" value="Join Now"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
        </form>
```

Ending of form tag.

Comment: then why cant you fill it?

Comment: this page may help you [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Now solve it bansi. If i know it then i wont ask it...

Comment: now we can solve it :)

Comment: Only the Email is blank?

Comment: When i fill the credentials(email and password) and click on the submit button. Then it checks for the code if right credential is there then it is redirected on the index page but if credential is wrong then page is reload and also email id textbox is empty. But i want that email textbox filled. If is there any query ask to me.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Part

```
<?php
$Email=''; //added here so the email is not confined to the else block (better practice to initilize).<------
if(isset($_POST["txtEmail"])){$Email =  $_POST["txtEmail"];} // this will ensure that even if you have not typed in the password the email still shows up.
if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
{   
if($_POST["txtEmail"]=="")
//rest of your code
```

in html part

```
<input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Email);?>" />
                                                                          // ^^ added here
```

You can post back any value like this.

Comment: Sorry bansi it also wont working

Comment: it works if you fill both email and password(tested).

Comment: check now, it will show up even if you have not typed in any password

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\meetmentors\connection.php:5) in C:\xampp\htdocs\meetmentors\login.php on line 42(header("Location:index.php");)

Comment: are you getting any warnings? you are having some output sent from line 5 of `connection.php` check that file (even an extra space outside `<?php .. ?>` tag counts as output).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
<input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email" value="<?php if(isset($Email)){echo $Email;} ?>" />
<!-- you might/want to escape $Email with something like htmlspecialchars -->
```

Comment: Sorry It wont working. It still displays blank after reload the page.

Comment: can you elaborate your english isn't that good to comprehend what youre trying to say. I read your english, but I see it as several things.